# Join VMSS VM's to domain

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set

It says here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-faq

That I can join a virtual machine scale set to an Azure AD domain, but I dont understand how you implement the JSON extension they state to use, I cant work out where I put it.
I have created the VMSS but cannot see an Extensions bit on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use script\dsc extensión as you normally would on a regular VM.

Sample DSC extensión:

```
{
    "name": "Microsoft.Powershell.DSC",
    "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
        "type": "DSC",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "2.19",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": {
            "configuration": {
                "url": "url_goes_here.ps1",
                "script": "script.ps1",
                "function": "function"
            },
            "configurationArguments": {
                "domainName": "domain.name"
            }
        },
        "protectedSettings": {
            "configurationArguments": {
                "adminCreds": {
                    "userName": "User",
                    "password": "Password"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So the only way to do it is with an Automation account?

Comment: you dont need automation account for that

Comment: I don't understand how I do it then? Do I need to do it in a template then create the vmss

Comment: yes, you need to add this extensión to the template. like in [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-vmss-windows-webapp-dsc-autoscale/azuredeploy.json) example

Comment: adding extensión? yes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/extensions-features